# Zend Metadata Cache in file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-cache, access-rights

I set up a metadata cache in Zend Framework because a *lot* of `DESCRIBE` queries were executed and it affected the performances.

```
$frontendOptions = array ('automatic_serialization' => true);
$backendOptions = array ('cache_dir' => CACHE_PATH . '/db-tables-metadata');
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
    'Core',
    'File',
    $frontendOptions,
    $backendOptions
);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
```

I can indeed see the cache files created, and the website works great.

However, when I launch unit tests, or a script of the same application that perform DB queries, I end up with an error because **Zend couldn't read the cache files**.

This is because in the website, **the cache files are created by the www user**, and when I run phpunit or a script, **it tries to read them with my user and it fails**.

Do you see any solution to that? I have some quickfix ideas but I'm looking for a good/stable solution. And I'd rather avoid running phpunit or the scripts as `www` if possible (for practical reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `sudo` command. something like this `$sudo -u www  php -f run-tests.php`

**edit**

maybe

```
$backendOptions = array ('cache_dir' => CACHE_PATH . '/db-tables-metadata', 'cache_file_umask' => 0755, 'cache_file_perm' => 0755);
```

Comment: I'd rather find a definitive fix than to have to remember to run my scripts using `sudo` everytime.

Comment: Oh I didn't see you edit (no notification), it seems really good I had no idea you could force the file rights!!! I will test it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Do you want cached table metadata during unit testing?  I'd normally disable that cache in development/testing.

You can try adding your test user to the `www` group (`usermod -a -G www testuser`).

Chances are that the cache files have standard `644` permissions which means your user still won't be able to modify the files, but if you set the permissions on the cache directory to `777` during testing then you should be able to write new files to that directory.

If you run PHP using CGI/FastCGI, you can have PHP run as your user rather than the generic `www` user.  Or if you are using an Apache module, [`mod_suphp`](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) will allow you to run PHP as your user as well.

Sorry its not too much help but hopefully can give you some more ideas..

Comment: Well thanks for the ideas. First, this is not only for development/testing, I have background scripts launched in production by different users. And unfortunately, access rights on the cache files are `-rw-------`, so can't be read at all by another user. And the directory is 777, but it tries to write the same files, so it throws an exception.

Comment: I see, depending on your OS, you may be able to install extended file access controls (e.g. [facl](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists) on Ubuntu).  You could use an ACL to allow certain users to read/write `www's` files.

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem of similar kind Later i could find that , Since I was running several other application server cache was getting clashed meaning two applications were using same cache , try naming the cacheobject for all types

and Also if you want you can also configure App.php file to create a different cache file for unit testing , This is a usual problem which occurs in shared hosting .